# How can I redirect user to another channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I want my bot to move the user to a specified voice channel when they try to join any other channel.

As far as I know:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => console.log(oldMember));
```

has been replaced by:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => console.log(oldState));
```

So how can I return the user who joins a voice channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user who joined a `VoiceChannel` using the `member` property of `VoiceState`.

```js
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {
    const Channel = client.channels.cache.get("ChannelID"); // The channel you want the user to be moved in.

    if (!Channel) return console.error("Invalid channel."); // Making sure the channel exists.

    if (!newState.channel) return false; // The user was disconnected from a channel.

    if (newState.channelID !== Channel.id) { // Checking if the user is in the wanted channel.
        newState.member.voice.setChannel(Channel).catch(error => console.error(error)); // Moving the user to the desired channel.
    };
});
```

I'd really recommend you to just deny the `Join Channel` permission instead of doing this.